# POST a form to colourbox iframe and open th result in iframe itself

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, colorbox

I have a form

```
<form method="POST" action="qwerty.php" />

<input type="text" name="merchant" />
<input type="text" name="password" />

<input type="submit" value="go" />

</form>
```

What I am trying to do is post this values into this php and get the result or reponse open up in the modal window it self.Is this possible? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

Using Ajax and  jquery this can be achieved like:

```
var merchant = $('form input:nth-child(1)').val();
var password= $('form input:nth-child(2)').val();

$('form input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
  $.post( "qwerty.php", { merchant: merchant, password: password }, function(data) {
    // #extraDiv is a div with display:none that will serve as a wrapper for the data
    $('#extraDiv').html(data).colorbox();

  });
});
```

Then in qwerty.php pick up the values u sent:

```
$merchant = $_POST['merchant'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
```

I am not so familiar with colorbox, but the above might work.

Comment: Imnot trying to pop an alert!I want to open the reponse in a colorbox iframe using ajax